# Not sure why my for loop is giving me an error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to loop through a list of data.

But the for loop is giving an illegal start of expression error. Here is the code:

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
    for(int i=0; i<ListArray.size(); i++) {
        new DataPoint((i),ListArray.get(i));
    }
});
graph.addSeries(series);
```

Comment: post full code here

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: Just in case you ever come back: please consider accepting one of the answers at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is meant to create an array and run a loop to simply create objects into each slot of that array.

It simply doesn't work this way. Go for

```
What [] ever = new... 
for (int i =0; i < ever.length ; i ++) {
  ever[i] =...
```

Instead.

Beyond that: you don't create easy to read code by pushing too many things into it. Meaning: if you want to encapsulate the array creation and filling simple move that code into a private helper method.